# Can you recover from a massive Git Error?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm not entirely certain what I did but I just lost a weeks worth of work in Git. I thought I could recover from my error but every single thing I do just makes it worse. There was a push error and I tried to go back to a previous pointer. Now my repo is practically unrecognizable. I thought it was always possible to recover your work in Git. When I look at each pointer, I can't even see the files anymore. Can git just straight up delete your work? If not, what steps do I need to take to recover? What information can I provide to help people help me? I'm using Atlassian source tree but I can use the command line too.

```
$ git reflog
0c5aa71 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to                                                        0c5aa71c2f25ab704bd5d726ba1f4d8685877680
c472404 HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to c4724042850c29427171c02f72ae754d3fe00254
c472404 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to master
c472404 HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to master
c472404 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to master
c472404 HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from master to master
c472404 HEAD@{6}: reset: moving to c4724042850c29427171c02f72ae754d3fe00254
bca4b8f HEAD@{7}: revert: Revert "A bunch of random work"
c472404 HEAD@{8}: commit: A bunch of random work
0c5aa71 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{9}: commit: New slide                                                        format
e7726ac HEAD@{10}: commit: Updates after moving active files to public folder.
2821d93 HEAD@{11}: commit: Initial Commit
e500340 HEAD@{12}: clone: from https://github.com/MassStreetAnalytics/data-wareh                                                       ouse-projects-source-material.git

git checkout c472404
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten
by checkout:
        Course Videos and Section Specific Slides/02 Data Warehouse Overview/
          0205 What technolgy do you need/0205 What technology do you need.pptx
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be removed by checkout:
        01 Introduction To The Course/01 Instructor Introduction/
          01 data-warehouse-projects.pptx
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Comment: No, it is not always possible to recover your work in git, using reset and force pushes it is quite easy to remove commits, and with the clean command it is easy to get rid of your unstaged changes.Exactly what you can do to recover, or even if it is possible at all, is entirely unclear without inspecting your repository. You could try looking at the reflog and seeing if your previous commits are still present. First, and foremost, **make a backup of your entire local folder**, the main reason people get into trouble with git is that they don't stop hacking when things go sour.

Comment: I've updated the question with my reflog. I need to get back to c472404 HEAD@{8}: commit: A bunch of random work.

Comment: I am using besides git an additional backup solution in case of restoration the files, which are ie. binary and should not be tracked. I recommend you the same.

Comment: I was doing that. The backup is apparently super effective and already captured the changes.

Comment: `git checkout c472404` followed by `git checkout -b TEMP`, then you have a branch pointing at that commit. Then you need to figure out **all the things that are wrong** with your repository. For instance, is `master` pointing to the right commit? Do you have the correct state in your TEMP branch? Figure out all of this **without executing git commands that modify commits**, then describe then here and people will follow up on it.

Comment: Question updated. When I run get checkout, I get the above. I get the same message for -b. I don't know what removing an untracked working tree will do. Am I safe to do that?

Comment: Getting back to a commit (without restoring anything that was not checked in at that point, of course) is as easy as doing a `git checkout <SHA>`. You know that and you tried that. Now the attempt to check out conflicts with uncommitted changes in your work tree. So move them aside (literally -- move the whole source directory elsewhere.) Once your source tree is empty you should be able to perform a clean checkout of that commit. Then you can see whether anything from your messed-up work tree files needs to be put back in there.

Comment: Untracked files are untracked, git does not care about them. Unless you have copies of them, either outside the repository or even on another branch where you *do* track them, then deleting them will delete them. The most important advice I can give you is that you 1. Make a backup of your folder (repository + working folder) and that you 2. Don't hack away with commands and actions you don't know the consequences of.

Comment: Move and check out! That got me back to where I needed to be! Thanks!

Comment: @BobWakefield That's nice to hear :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write my comment as a quick answer.

If you have conflicts with local, uncommitted work tree changes when you try to perform a checkout (or merge, or pull, or anything that changes the work tree with files from the repo) git stops, because it doesn't know whether the work that would be overwritten is valuable to you.

You can simply delete the conflicting files or, if you are unsure, move them to an unrelated location for later inspection. Then the checkout of an arbitrary commit should proceed without any problems.

After that you can manually apply edits you actually want to preserve which are present in the saved files, for example with a compare/merge tool that can handle directories.

Comment: Yup moving files got me back where I needed to be! NICE!